# React render object is not extensible

Tags: javascript, reactjs

the react code below gives me the following error I have a series of values ​​that are loaded and that must be inserted in an array of javascript objects and then displayed in a datatable, what is the error due to? I inserted the function that performs the loading of the list in react
**Error:**

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible
_callee$
src/pages/cantieri/RistorantiView.js:39
  36 |   var result = await caricamentoristoranti(this.props.IdCantiere);
  37 |   console.log("Ristoranti caricati: "+result.length+"\n per idCantiere: "+this.props.IdCantiere);
  38 |   for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
> 39 |     this.rowsLoad.push({ id: result[i].IdRistorante, ragionesociale: result[i].RagioneSociale, datainserimento: result[i].DataInserimento, costo: result[i].Costo });
     | ^  40 |   }
  41 | }
```

**React Code:**

```
const columns = [
  { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 200 },
  { field: "ragionesociale", headerName: "Ragione Sociale", width: 200 },
  { field: "datainserimento", headerName: "Data Inserimento", width: 200 },
  { field: "costo", headerName: "Costo", width: 200 },
];
    class DataTableRistoranti extends React.Component{
       
      rowsLoad=[];
    
      async componentDidMount() {
        var result = await caricamentoristoranti(this.props.IdCantiere);
        console.log("Ristoranti caricati: "+result.length+"\n per idCantiere: "+this.props.IdCantiere);
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
          this.rowsLoad.push({ id: result[i].IdRistorante, ragionesociale: result[i].RagioneSociale, datainserimento: result[i].DataInserimento, costo: result[i].Costo });
        }
      }
      
      render() {
        return(
        <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%",background: "White" }}>
          <DataGrid background="White" rows={this.rowsLoad} columns={columns} pcostoSize={5} checkboxSelection />
        </div>
      );
        }
    }

//Caricamento ristoranti
export async function caricamentoristoranti(IdCantiere) {
  var lista=[];

  await axios.post(server.url+'/ristoranti/carica', {
    IdCantiere: IdCantiere
    })
    .then(function (response) {

      let data = response.data;
      for (let index in data){
        var datatemp={
          "Data" : data[index].Data,
          "Costo" : data[index].Costo,
          "DataInserimento" :  data[index].DataInserimento,
         "ExtraPreventivo" : data[index].ExtraPreventivo,
         "IdCantiere" : data[index].IdCantiere,
         "IdRistorante" : data[index].IdRistorante,
         "IdUtenteInserimento" : data[index].IdUtenteInserimento,
         "RagioneSociale" : data[index].RagioneSociale,
         "InseritoDA" : data[index].InseritoDA

        };
        lista.push(datatemp);
      }

      }).catch(function (error) {

    });

    return lista;

}
```

Comment: You are returning an empty ```lista``` in ```caricamentoristoranti```. Study about ```Asynchronous```

Comment: list is not empty, i have check with line:   console.log("Ristoranti caricati: "+result.length+"\n per idCantiere: "+this.props.IdCantiere);

Comment: Yes, you right. but rare using ```await``` and ```then``` together!

Comment: oh,oh. You have to trigger ```setState``` then react will update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding rowsLoad inside the constructor.

```
class DataTableRistoranti extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        rowsLoad=[]
     } //add here
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    var result = await caricamentoristoranti(this.props.IdCantiere);
    console.log(
      "Ristoranti caricati: " +
        result.length +
        "\n per idCantiere: " +
        this.props.IdCantiere
    );
    const rowsLoad = result.map((r) => ({ // change here
      id: r.IdRistorante,
      ragionesociale: r.RagioneSociale,
      datainserimento: r.DataInserimento,
      costo: r.Costo,
    })
    )

    setState({rowsLoad});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%", background: "White" }}>
        <DataGrid
          background="White"
          rows={this.state.rowsLoad}
          columns={columns}
          pcostoSize={5}
          checkboxSelection
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried your solution but still the same error

Comment: Now it no longer generates the error but the values ​​are not loaded into the datagrid

Comment: @riki check now

Comment: i have try your new solution but i have this error in console: index.js:1375 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `rows` is marked as required in `ForwardRef`, but its value is `undefined`.
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:1450

Comment: now you have to use `this.state.rowsLoad`

Answer (score 0):

```
class DataTableRistoranti extends React.Component{
      constructor() {
         this.state = {
            rowsLoad=[];
         }
      }       
    
      async componentDidMount() {
        var result = await caricamentoristoranti(this.props.IdCantiere);
        this.setState({rowsLoad: result})
      }
```